# Showing that 2 elements of a vectorspace are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know how to solve the following problem. Suppose that dim(V) = n and W = $\mathbb{R}$. The vectorspace V* = Hom(V, $\mathbb{R}$) is called the dual space of V. An element $\phi$ $\in$ V* is called a (linear) functional. Now, suppose that v, w $\in$ V such that $\phi$(v) = $\phi$(w) for all $\phi$ $\in$ V*. Can we conclude that v = w?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $\phi(v-w)=0$ for all $\phi\in V^*$ implies that $v-w=0$, see the duplicate.

Comment: Excuse me. In the previous exercise I was given Hom(V, W). So now, in this exercise, W = $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: that had to be 'and'